# Wp-api cookie authentication wpApiSettings is not defined

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have this script to add a new post to a website via API but I get wpApiSettings is not defined all the time.

This is how I enqueue a script in my functions.php:

```
function api_test() {
    wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
        'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
    ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'api_test' );
```

and this is how I try to insert the post:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
    method: 'POST',
    data: objData,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you created the array wpApiSettings in the function api_test()?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in functions.php and check if the user has the capabilities to perform the action.

```
wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array( 'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ) ) );
wp_enqueue_script('wp-api');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added my scripts at the footer and it work

```
function api_test() {
   wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
      'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
   ) );
   wp_enqueue_script('app.script', '<script>/*call ajax here*/</script>');
}


add_action('wp_footer', 'api_test', 5);
```

Or

```
add_action('in_admin_footer', 'api_test');
```

Comment: This is not working in my case. I really don't understand how WP can make anything difficult on so many levels and so difficult to intuit.